# Finding a Complement to the Subspace of all Linear Functions

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

Let $V = \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ be the vector space (over $\mathbb{R}$) of all functions mapping $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.  Let $U$ be the subspace of all linear functions (functions of the form $f(x)=mx + b$ for some $m,b\in\mathbb{R}$).  Note that the zero vector $\vec{0}$ is the function $f(x)=0$, $\forall x$.

I am trying to find a complement to $U$, in other words a subspace $W \leq V$ such that $W \cap U = \{\vec{0}\}$ and $\text{span}(W \cup U) = V$.

Given that $U$ is 2-dimensional and $V$ is infinite-dimensional, I know that $W$ must be infinite dimensional.  As a starting point I was considering the set of all non-linear functions along with $\vec{0}$ but clearly that is not closed under vector addition since $y=x+x^2$ and $y=x-x^2$ for instance could be added to get a linear function.  I was also considering some weird edge cases like
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 
      x & \text{if $x\neq 1$} \\
      0 & \text{if $x=1$}
   \end{cases}$$
$$g(x) = \begin{cases} 
      x & \text{if $x \neq 1$}\\
      2 & \text{if $x=1$}
   \end{cases}$$
Then clearly $f(x) + g(x)$ is a linear function ($y=2x$), but $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are not linear functions, so both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ would have to be in $\text{span}(U \cup W)$ but at least 1 would have to not be in $W$ (and neither could be in $U$).  Similar examples could be constructed with other discontinuities / weird cases.  I can't think of any general description for $U$ that would satisfy all of these cases and all the other possible cases (and also be a subspace).

Any tips would be appreciated (my progress on this problem seems to be stuck for the moment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the space of functions $f$ such that $f(0)=f(1)=0$.